# How to prevent Graphics mode from running

Tags: startup

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and it was in text mode, so I did apt-get install gnome and now it starts in graphics mode no matter what I try.

What I want to do is start in text mode and run the graphics mode when I need it with startx gnome.

It is a server so graphics are not normally needed but there are occasions when graphics mode is handy, I also want to exit back to the command prompt when I quit graphics mode.

I could do this easily with old versions of Linux before this darn grub thing, like all grubs it is a pest.

Can any body help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the file `/etc/default/grub` You will need root privileges.

Look for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

and replace with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`

Now `sudo update-grub` to update grub configuration and you are set to go.